# Unsafe Stack in C#

Tags: c#, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel, stack

I was interested to see if it was possible to implement an unsafe stack in C#, so I wrote this:

```
public unsafe struct Node
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Node* Next { get; set; }
}

public unsafe class Stack
{
    Node* first;

    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public void Push(int value)
    {
        var oldFirst = first;
        first = (Node*)(Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(Node)));
        first->Value = value;
        first->Next = oldFirst;
        Count++;
    }

    public int Pop()
    {
        if(Count == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException();

        int item = first->Value;
        first = first->Next;
        Count--;
        return item;
    }
}
```

**Test method:**

```
void Main()
{
    Stack stack = new Stack();

    for(int i = 1; i <= 1000;i++)
        stack.Push(i);

    double sum = 0;
    while(stack.Count != 0) sum += stack.Pop();
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

**Output:** `500500`

Is there something wrong with this?  Is it possible to make it generic?

Comment: And why do you need an unsafe stack?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi For educational purposes.

Comment: This is a bad example of educational code. For one, it is not just `unsafe`, it's very unsafe. Where's error handling etc.? There's a lot of places here where you leak memory. There's no gain from using `unsafe` in the first place. And while it is a stack, it doesn't really do anything to give you the usual performance benefits from using a stack. Maybe you should go deeper in your education, and try to work with expandable virtual memory stack or something like that?

Comment: @Luaan This is not for real-world use. I'm just trying to see what C#s capabilities are.

Comment: I wouldn't even dream of using the in the real world :D Right now, you've only explored the problems with unmanaged memory in general, and not really C# at all. You need to make sure all the memory is released - both when `Pop`ping and when the reference to the stack is un-rooted. And most importantly, you're not gaining any benefit from having this unmanaged. In fact, even in C++, you wouldn't do this in a completely unmanaged fashion. You should use this opportunity to learn about writing defensive code and finalizers.

Comment: @Luaan I have some knowledge of pointers and dealing with memory in C. I somehow forgot to free memory in `Pop`. That's embarrassing.

Answer (score 8):

Your stack seems to be leaking memory. When you want to use native `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` (which is like `malloc` in C), you have to free the memory as well in `Pop()`.

```
public int Pop()
{
    if(Count == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException();

    int item = first->Value;
    Node* node = first;         // take it to local
    first = first->Next;
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)node);  // dispose/free the memory
    Count--;
    return item;
}
```

And it should be made [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IDisposable.aspx) to do the same for all the nodes in destructor (at least this way, but IDisposable is prefered in such case).

---

The following is the idea of generic implementation with `IDisposable`:
*(hope I got it right, untested)*

```
public unsafe class Stack<T>: IDisposable {
    protected struct Node {  // implementation detail should not be public
        public Node* next;   // just my preference to have the pointer first
        public IntPtr value; // discussed later
    }
    ~Stack() { // this is destructor (called when garbage collected)
        Dispose(false);
    }
    public void Dispose() { // this is implementation of IDisposable - see keyword using
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this); // prevents calling destructor, we have done the job
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        while(Count > 0) Pop(); // make sure all unmanaged memory got released
    }
```

It is not possible to have managed pointers in unmanaged (unsafe/fixed) struct (there would be no way for GC to change such pointers in unmanaged space), but there still is a way to make it generic - links:

[SO: Implementing a generic unmanaged array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388303/implementing-a-generic-unmanaged-array-in-c-sharp)
[MSDN: Marshal.PtrToStructure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Unmanaged pointers to managed objects are only valid within `fixed` contex, where the managed memory is pinned in place, but after leaving the `fixed` context, the memory can be moved (when there is no reference to object with lower address) or reclaimed (as there is no hint that a reference exist).

Implementing such generic unmanaged Stack would need some `Marshal` magic, type checking and casting. Simple native types and structures smaller than IntPtr could be casted, bigger structs allocated on unmanaged heap (proper allocation/deallocation needed), some specific objects like strings could be handled as native arrays and converted both ways. **Totally generic approach (for any managed class) is not possible** and runtime errors (from `Marshal`) will be the result of it (but not unsafe, this can still be made safe, but not compile-time checked).

This is getting too StackOverflow-ish, too far from CR. I will (propbably) leave it with those ideas and without implementation.

Comment: Not to mention that using `AllocHGlobal` to push something to the stack is quite an expensive way to do that. This is not going to be a fast stack :D

Comment: Agreed, I would use managed growing array.... but that is different story :)

Comment: @firda Actually `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(node)` should be `Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)node)`

Comment: Corrected and added link to IDisposable where you can see how to implement it (e.g. by `while (Count > 0) Pop()`)

Comment: Your generic implementation doesn't compile (Not because of the missing brace).

Comment: It won't compile probably because you can't have a pointer to a reference type or to a struct that contains reference types. `Stack<T> where T:struct` doesn't work because T may be a struct that contains reference types.

Comment: Ahh, yes, forgot about that limitation. You cannot reference managed from unmanaged (there is no way to track managed pointers in unmanaged code). And C# is no C++, generics are no templates. Good try with `T:struct` constraint. I will leave it here as it is for a while if anybody can come up with better idea. Hope the IDisposable is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Because you have decided to declare `Node` as a `struct`, then you have to make it `immutable`, because mutable structs are evil, [and thats a good read if you want to know why](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/mutating-readonly-structs)

And it's not that hard

```
 public unsafe struct Node
 {
    public readonly int Value;
    public readonly Node* Next;

    public Node(int value,Node* next)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.Next = next;
    }

    public Node ChangeNext(Node * newNext)
    {
        return new Node (this.Value, newNext);
    }
}
```

And by doing this, you don't need to mutate a node for changing its `next` node

```
  unsafe{
        Node first = new Node (1, null);
        Node next = new Node (2, null);
        first = first.ChangeNext (&next);
        Console.WriteLine (first.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(first.Next->Value);

        }
```

Comment: Good hint if we would not be in `unsafe` context with pointers and authors desire to make it generic, where the value can actually be another big struct - I would not use immutable in such scenairo (because of the *all native with pointers* here). Your code moved it to managed.

Comment: The evilness of mutable structs is often exaggerated. Internal storage of collections is one of the places where mutable structs are often a good choice. Simply avoiding methods on a struct that mutate `this` prevents most of the pitfalls.

Comment: I would call it `WithNext` instead of `ChangeNext`; I think 'change' kind of implies that it's mutating it.

Comment: @DavidConrad yeah perhaps, but isn't it clear because it returns a Node?

Comment: Perhaps. That is certainly a clue.

Comment: Why do you have `ChangeNext()` in the first place? I don't see any place in the original code where it would be useful.

Comment: The supposed evilness of mutable structures [which in reality aren't evil, but instead are a data type that isn't an object and thus shouldn't be *expected* to behave like one] pales in comparison with the evil of persisting raw pointers.  Anyone who doesn't understand how structures work isn't apt to know everything that's necessary to persist raw pointers safely, and the idea of a function returning a type containing raw pointer isn't part of the recipe.

Comment: There are many cases where safe usage of a structure types requires that they be *edited in place*.  Whether you prefer the syntax `thing.MutatingMethod()` [which is cleaner but doesn't guard against having a compiler generate a temp variable in some cases and pass that] or `StructType.MutatingMethod(ref thing)` [which is ugly, but guards against such compiler behavior], in-place editing is generally necessary to ensure that pointer ownership can be fully tracked at all times.

Comment: Is this line taking a pointer to stack `first = first.ChangeNext (&next);`? Then `first` is (native/unmanaged) pointer, so, it should not compile and changing it to `first = &first.ChangeNext (&next)` is heading us to another crash (pointer to temporary / stack object).